# Can I change background map in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I just had a play with ggplot2 in R, with syntax like

```
geom_map(data=world, map=world
aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
color="white", fill="#7f7f7f", size=0.05, alpha=1/4)
```

That gives me the world map, is it possible to only get UK map as background map? 
Many thanks
Peddie

Comment: Syntax looks flawed. Missing comma or parenthesis. Edit question.

Comment: Sorry I only copied and pasted part of the script. I hope to get advice on data and map, I saw a lot of samples like data=world, map=world, can I replace world with specific countries e.g UK? I did try UK but that throws error.

Comment: Have you tried subsetting the data as in `map_uk <- map_data('world') %>% filter(region == 'UK')` ?

Answer (score 8):

You can also do something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)

gbr <- getData("GADM", country="GBR", level=0)
gbr <- gSimplify(gbr, 0.01)

gbr_map <- fortify(gbr)

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=gbr_map, data=gbr_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    fill="#7f7f7f")
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

Once my `ggalt` package is in CRAN you can even use a decent projection.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! One more thing please - is it possible to actually have uk map zoom in particular area eg south east England or by defined lat / long? Many thanks

Comment: Try changing the `coord_map()` call to `gg <- gg + coord_map(xlim=c(-4, 2), ylim=c(50, 53))`

Comment: wow that really works too you are a genius! one last question - how do you work out xlim, ylim?

Comment: by looking at a map with labeled graticules (i.e. lat/lon lines with #'s)

Answer (score 3):

Also check out [ggplot2::borders()](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/borders.html)

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot() + 
  borders(reg="UK", color="white", fill="#7f7f7f", alpha=1/4)
```

The result should be equal to the one from @eipi10.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

dat=map_data("world")

ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data=dat[dat$region=="UK",], map=dat[dat$region=="UK",],
         aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
         color="white", fill="#7f7f7f", size=0.05, alpha=1/4) +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The library `ggmap` works very well with ggplot2.

You could try this:

```
library(ggmap)

#Google API
register_google(key = "your_api_key")

map <- get_map(location = 'UK', zoom = 6)
ggmap(map)
```

and add `geom` as you like.

Comment: ggmap is now (summer 2020) effectively defunct.

Comment: @gregmacfarlane, what do you mean defunct? My code is still working. You just need to have a Google API and run this line `register_google(key = "your_api_key")` before mine. So I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: I suppose it's philosophical; using Google Maps as the background layer in open research is a tricky philosophical issue, and the OpenStreetMap functionality has been eliminated. https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/issues/117

Comment: I might suggest an edit to specify that the google API is now required.